# Doubt in the differentiability of single variable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

In physics, I have studied that a function $f(x)$ is said to be differentiable at $x_o$ if
$\Delta y=f'(x_o)\Delta x+\epsilon\Delta x$
where $\epsilon\to 0$ when $\Delta x\to 0$.

In real analysis books, I have studied that a function $f(x)$ is said to be differentiable at $x_o$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to x_o}\frac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}$ exists (denote it by $f'(x_o)$).

If we proceed in this manner then,
$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\;s.t.\;\forall x\in N'_\delta(x_o),|x-x_o|<\delta \implies \lvert\frac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}-f'(x_o)\rvert<\epsilon$
Put $\Delta y=f(x)-f(x_o)$ and $\Delta x=x-x_o$
So,$\lvert\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-f'(x_o)\rvert<\epsilon$
$\implies \lvert\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-f'(x_o)\rvert\lvert\Delta x\rvert<\epsilon\lvert\Delta x\rvert$
$\implies \lvert\Delta y-f'(x_o)\Delta x\rvert<\epsilon\lvert\Delta x\rvert$
As $\lvert a\rvert-\lvert b\rvert\leq\lvert a-b\rvert$
$\implies \lvert\Delta y\rvert-\lvert f'(x_o)\Delta x\rvert<\epsilon\lvert\Delta x\rvert$
Hence,  $\lvert\Delta y\rvert<\lvert f'(x_o)\Delta x\rvert+\epsilon\lvert\Delta x\rvert$
Here also $\epsilon\to 0$ when $\Delta x\to 0$

If I proceed by the definition we study in real analysis, I get strict inequality and absolute values while the expression on the top given in physics book has equality ($\Delta y=f'(x_o)\Delta x+\epsilon\Delta x$).

My question is why this is so? Why I get different expressions? Am I missing something?
Please clarify the doubt.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is fixed in any $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof. So, if you run that limit you refer to at the end, you will just end up with $0<\epsilon$.

Comment: You are confused between two things: 1) $\epsilon$ in the first case is a function depending upon $x$ that tends to 0 as $x\to x_0$. 2) $\epsilon\gt 0$ in second case is an “arbitrarily chosen positive number “. It can be 50000, 0.000000001 etc. and then you’ll get delta. Note that it’s not the other way round. That is given a delta, you may not have an epsilon.

Comment: Contd... You can understand Physics notation like this: $\Delta y=f(x)-f(x_0)=f’(x_0) \Delta x+o(\Delta x)$ where $o(\Delta x)$ is function such that $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{o(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}=0$. Using this you can show the two definitions to be equivalent (that is one implies and is implied by the other).

Comment: Ok, so physics notation is like Taylor expansion. if $x$ id very very close to $x_o$, then $f(x)-f(x_o)=f'(x_o)(x-x_o)$, we can neglect the higher order terms.